# Web api netcore set Cors in appsettings.json file

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi

I'm using a webapi .netcore project.
I want to put all the cross settings in the appsettings.json file.
How do I do this?

This is my code:

```
 app.UseCors(x => x.WithOrigins("http://localhost:4200")
    .AllowCredentials()
    .WithHeaders("content-type")
    .WithMethods("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE"));
```

Comment: What do you mean by putting the cross settings in appsetting?

Comment: I can change the settings in the appsettings.json file.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to set the CORS settings in `appsettings.json` and use the settings in `startup.cs`, you can follow the code below:

This is my `appsettings.json`:

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "AllowedOrigins": "http://localhost:4200",
  "AllowedHeaders": "content-type",
  "AllowedMethods": "GET,POST,PUT,DELETE"
}
```

This is my partial code in `startup.cs`:

```
app.UseCors(x => x.WithOrigins(Configuration.GetSection("AllowedOrigins").Value.Split(","))
                  .AllowCredentials().WithHeaders(Configuration.GetSection("AllowedHeaders").Value.Split(","))
                  .WithMethods(Configuration.GetSection("AllowedMethods").Value.Split(",")));

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
```